# Compare characters in column next row

Tags: r, dataframe

My data is:

```
Name    House   Street  Apt City    Postal  Phone
Bob Joe     954 BLUE DRIVE  NA  A PLACE Z5K4N2  999-495-6544
Smith Jane  555 BLUE DRIVE  NA  A PLACE Z5K4N5  999-435-6172
Smith Jane  555 BLUE DRIVE  NA  A PLACE Z5K4N5  999-450-6763
```

I am trying to compare Names (dynamically, and the data is sorted by House), if equal AND house # is equal, concatenate the respective two phone numbers and delete the row thats not concatenated.

So it would look like this after:

```
 Name   House   Street      Apt City    Postal  Phone
Bob Joe     954 BLUE DRIVE  NA  A PLACE Z5K4N2  999-495-6544
Smith Jane  555 BLUE DRIVE  NA  A PLACE Z5K4N5  999-435-6172 OR 999-450-6763
```

My attempt:

```
for(x in 1:nrow(data)) {

     if(data$Name[x] == data$Name[x+1]) {
     data$NameDupes <- data$Name[x] }
 }
```

And then after that use

```
aggregate: aggregate(Phone ~ Name + Street + City + Postal + Apt + House, data = df, paste, collapse = " OR ")
```

and then after that, use a join on my original df.

open to ideas

Thanks

Comment: Your `aggregate` code is failing because the Apt variable contains NAs, so cannot be properly used as a grouping variable. To Fix this, change these values to "NONE" or 0 or something. For example, `df$Apt[is.na(df$Apt)] <- " "` and then your final line of code will work to combine rows 2 and 3 in your example.

Answer (score 2):

A solution from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(House, Street, Apt, City, Postal) %>%
  summarise(Name = first(Name), Phone = paste(Phone, collapse = " OR ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(House)) %>%
  select(colnames(dt))
dt2
# A tibble: 2 x 7
        Name House     Street   Apt    City Postal                        Phone
       <chr> <int>      <chr> <lgl>   <chr>  <chr>                        <chr>
1    Bob Joe   954 BLUE DRIVE    NA A PLACE Z5K4N2                 999-495-6544
2 Smith Jane   555 BLUE DRIVE    NA A PLACE Z5K4N5 999-435-6172 OR 999-450-6763
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Name    House   Street  Apt City    Postal  Phone
'Bob Joe'     954 'BLUE DRIVE'  NA  'A PLACE' Z5K4N2  '999-495-6544'
'Smith Jane'  555 'BLUE DRIVE'  NA  'A PLACE' Z5K4N5  '999-435-6172'
'Smith Jane'  555 'BLUE DRIVE'  NA  'A PLACE' Z5K4N5  '999-450-6763'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A different answer than that of @ycw... using data.table. (Because I am a personal fan of the package).

Using the data

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Name    House   Street  Apt City    Postal  Phone
'Bob Joe'     954 'BLUE DRIVE'  NA  'A PLACE' Z5K4N2  '999-495-6544'
'Smith Jane'  555 'BLUE DRIVE'  NA  'A PLACE' Z5K4N5  '999-435-6172'
'Smith Jane'  555 'BLUE DRIVE'  NA  'A PLACE' Z5K4N5  '999-450-6763'",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We perform a great one-liner

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(dt)
dt[,.(Phone = paste(Phone,collapse = " OR ")),by = .(Name,House,Street,Apt,City,Postal)]
```

that outputs

```
     Name House     Street Apt    City Postal                        Phone
1:    Bob Joe   954 BLUE DRIVE  NA A PLACE Z5K4N2                 999-495-6544
2: Smith Jane   555 BLUE DRIVE  NA A PLACE Z5K4N5 999-435-6172 OR 999-450-6763
```

Comment: You could just start out with `fread` to return a data.table initially. Or if you want to perform the conversion `setDT` is preferable to `as.data.table`, because the perform performs the conversion in place, meaning no copies are made. In fact, you could just do `setDT(dt)[ <data.table code>` and perform the conversion in the same line as your code.

Comment: @Imo Of course, but the problem was not to convert to a data.table as efficient as possible.